# MySQL select date to date

Tags: php, mysql

About MySQL select date to date
I have datatable

TABLE A

```
ID | DATE
-----------------
1  | 2012-01-01
2  | 2012-01-12
3  | 2012-01-20
4  | 2012-02-03
5  | 2012-02-13
6  | 2012-02-14
7  | 2012-04-05
```

I want to show like this . 
And I want use Only MySQL .

```
 DATE
--------------------
 01,12,20 Jan 2012
 03,13,14 Fab 2012
 05 Apr 2012
```

OR

```
 DATE
--------------------
 01-01-2012,12-01-2012,20-01-2012
 03-02-2012,13-02-2012,14-02-2012 
 05-03-2012
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second form, you could combine [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(`DATE`, '%b %Y') AS Month
  ,      GROUP_CONCAT(`DATE`)         AS Dates
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY Month
```

For the first form, you can use [`DAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) within [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(`DATE`, '%b %Y') AS Month
  ,      GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(`DATE`))    AS Dates
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty easy - Select your dates from the database in ascending date order then loop through each record (using localtime or one of the other time functions where you can get the month), storing the days in a string until you find a record with a different month / year, then print that month string and start a new one for that month.

Probably also worth using the date names from PHP to avoid date names like 'Fab' :)

Comment: So why did you add PHP in the tags?

Comment: Because , I want use only mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DATE SEPARATOR ',') FROM TABLEA
```

OR

```
select CONCAT_WS(' ',GROUP_CONCAT(a.day1 SEPARATOR ','),a.month1,a.year1) as `DATE` from (select DAY(`DATE`) as day1,DATE_FORMAT(`DATE`,'%b') as month1, YEAR(`DATE`) as year1 from TABLEA) a group by a.month1, a.year1
```